# make node webkit app load full screen

Tags: node-webkit

I'm trying to build a node-webkit app, currently I'm experimenting on `package.json`

Here is the contents so far:

```
{
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "main": "index.html",
  "window": {
    "title": "node-webkit demo",
    "icon": "icon.png",
    "toolbar": false,
    "frame": true,
    "fullscreen": true
  }
}
```

How do I make my node-webkit app load on fullscreen?

[**Docs**](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Manifest-format#fullscreen) says:

`(boolean) whether window is fullscreen (available after node-webkit v0.3.0)`

So why didn't the above `package.json` work?

Comment: The above code worked fine for me. What version of node-webkit are you using?

Comment: @gotohales I did a `process.version` and it says `v0.11.13-pre`. I'm gonna try  older versions and see what will happen. At least I have confirmation that the code is right. thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Confirmed. Full screen on v0.10.5 (node.js v0.11.13-pre) doesn't work for me either on Windows. I can notice it attempts to full screen but then goes back to a window for some reason.

This isn't an ideal answer, but this is a workaround I've been using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <script>
    var ngui = require('nw.gui');
    var nwin = ngui.Window.get();
    nwin.enterFullscreen();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Full screen still works via the JavaScript call.

Answer (score 4):

Nw.js has a special `kiosk` [mode](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/The-Kiosk-mode):

```
{
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "main": "index.html",
  "window": {
    "title": "node-webkit demo",
    "icon": "icon.png",
    "toolbar": false,
    "frame": true,
    "kiosk": true // set kiosk mode true
  }
}
```